# Facebook graph api always returns error : Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Network is unreachable

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook's redirect helper.

The helper works fine but error occurs at login-callback.php.
Here's my login-callback.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'functions.php';                       //a file I require         

session_start();

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

  try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email', $accessToken);

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$user = $response->getGraphUser();

$name=$user['name'];

$id = $user->getId();

$email = $user->getEmail();    

$id='f'.$id;

$result=queryMysql("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='".$id."'");

if(!$result->num_rows)
 {
  $result=queryMysql("INSERT INTO user VALUES('$id','$name','$email')");
 }
$_SESSION['logger']='facebook';
header('Location: http://localhost/fee/index.php');

}
?>
```

Graph api and $helper->accessToken gives me the following error.

Sometimes $helper->accessToken works and i receive access token but graph api never works.

The error I get is : 
Facebook SDK returned an error: Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Network is unreachable

Comment: That means there is a network-related issue on your server. Go ask the server admin to look into it.

Comment: But if I remove Graph api call, it works fine.